# Why does setting useState inside a loop perform differently?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, use-state

Can someone explain the following code snippet to me please? Why does handleClick() not work properly (only 1 or 2 of the data properties of newData are set) whereas handleClick2() works properly.

I am guessing the problem is due to the loop (since that is the only difference), but why does a loop cause this effect?

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-surf-u9i5s?file=/src/App.js:0-969

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";


const App = () => {
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState({
    data1: '',
    data2: '',
    data3: '',
    data4: ''
  })

  const handleClick = () => {
    let fields = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']
    let field
    for (field of fields) {
        setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, [field]: 'test'}))
    }
  }

  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, data1: 'test'}))
    setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, data2: 'test'}))
    setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, data3: 'test'}))
    setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, data4: 'test'}))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('State: ' + JSON.stringify(newData))
  }, [newData])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>Click2</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is:

`setNewData` is async function. When you call `setNewData` somehow React will push its callback function in event loop then call it back in main thread when the main thread empty. When `setNewData` callback function is call in main `field` is `test4` because  `for (field of fields)` sync function. ==> only `setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, data4: 'test'}))` is call 4 times.

You can log the `field` inside of `setNewData` callback function and see the value of it.

```
for (field of fields) {
  console.log(field)
  setNewData(oldState => {
    console.log(field)
    return { ...oldState, [field]: "test" }
  })
}
```

[Codesandbox for it](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-yonath-vd6xu?file=/src/App.js:309-479)

Comment: Thank you. But what makes the difference in looping it vs running 4 calls side by side?

Comment: When you call  4 calls side by side such as  `setNewData(oldState => ({...oldState, data1: 'test'}))` and so on, they are not depending on `field`. when each of them is called back in main thread, js knows `data1: "test"` NOT `[field]: "test"`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation!